# Solve $x,y,z, z^x=x, z^y=y, y^y=x$

Tags: systems-of-equations, exponentiation

I solved it and got three solutions

$(1,1,1)$ is obvious, no need to calculate it.

other two solutions are $(4,2\sqrt{2}),(4,2,-\sqrt{2})$

But actual answer is only $(1,1,1),(4,2,\sqrt{2})$.

One can see that all these three triplets are satisfying the equation.

What am I missing here.

My attempt is as follows:

$$z^x=x$$
$$x\log (z)=\log (x)$$
$$\log (z)=\frac {\log (x)}{x}$$
$$z^y=y$$
$$\log (z)=\frac {\log (y)}{y}$$

$$\frac {x}{y}=\frac {\log (x)}{\log (y)}$$
$$y^y=x$$
$$y\log (y)=\log (x)$$
$$y=\frac {\log (x)}{\log (y)}$$
$$x=y^2$$

$$y^y=x$$
$$y^y=y^2$$
$$y=2$$
$$x=2^2$$
$$x=4$$
$$z=\sqrt{2},-\sqrt{2}$$

Comment: Obviously, your solution is correct, so the problem probably assumed $z>0$. If it doesn't specify that, then the published answer is wrong.

Comment: my only concern is that,I used log here and in the middle of calculations, I am doing log(z) ,which indicates z>0, but surprisingly negative value of z is satisfying the original equation

Comment: Well, your derivation assumes $x>0,y>0,z>0$ but that doesn't invalidate your answers.

Comment: @saulspatz, exactly but interesting answer , another user is saying $\sqrt{-2}$ is not the valid answer.

Comment: Who is "he"?  You don't mean $\sqrt{-2}$ though; you mean $-\sqrt{2}$ as you wrote in the question.

Comment: yeah sorry for that, I mean $-\sqrt{2}$, he is @Quanto

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99827/discussion-between-user3290550-and-saulspatz).

Answer (score 2):

$z=-\sqrt{2}$ is not permissible.

This is because $\log(-\sqrt2)$, which is used in your derivation, is undefined. This spurious solution comes about because $y$ happens to be 2.

Edit:

As pointed out below in the comments, the function $z^y$ is defined for the domain $z>0$, which is implicit. To see why, for example, $(-1)^{1/2} \ne (-1)^{2/4}$, indicating that $z^y$ could have different  values for $z=-1$ and can not be viewed as a function for negative value $z$. If any negative value is allowed for the solution, it needs to be explicitly stated in the question.

Comment: yeah, that is my confusion , because it is satisfying the original equation which ultimately matters, isn't.

Comment: Please note that the domain of the function $z^y$ is normally defined as $z>0$

Comment: no but z can take all real values here , as well as y can take all values here

Comment: Only in special cases. For example, $(-0.1)^{\frac12}$ is undefined. You may expand your function domain and redefine a function for certain cases to allow for negative values. But, as $z^y$ is given in the question, it is implicit that $z>0$

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution without using the logarithm function.  In this way, the solution $(x,y,z)=(4,2,-\sqrt{2})$ cannot be excluded.

However, it should be noted, as in Quanto's answer, that the function $z\mapsto z^y$ is generally not defined for $z\leq 0$ (or it needs to be clearly stated how it is defined), since we do not know a priori that $y$ will end up being an integer.  However, at least, this solution works if we assume that $a^b$ is always defined whenever $b\in\mathbb{Z}$ (except possibly when $a=0$).

From $z^x=x$, $z^y=y$, and $y^y=x$, we have
$$y^{y^2}=\left(y^y\right)^y=x^y=\left(z^x\right)^y=z^{xy}=\left(z^y\right)^x=y^x\,.$$
Hence,
$$y^{y^2-x}=1\,.$$
That is, $y=1$, $y=-1$ and $y^2-x$ is an even integer, or $y^2=x$.

If $y=1$, then $x=1$, so $z=1$.  If $y=-1$ and $y^2-x$ is an even integer, then $x=y^y=-1$, so $z^x=x$ means $z=-1$.  Thus, if $|y|=1$, we get the solutions
$$(x,y,z)=\pm(1,1,1)\,.$$

If $|y|\neq 1$, then $y^2=x=y^y$, or $y^{y-2}=1$.  Thus, $y=2$ and so $x=4$.  This implies $z^2=2$ (and $z^4=4$), or $z=\pm\sqrt{2}$, whence
$$(x,y,z)=(4,2,\pm\sqrt{2})$$
are solutions.

**P.S.** I just realized that $y^{y^2-x}=1$ can also happen when $y=-1$ and $y^2-x$ is an even integer, and edited this answer accordingly.